# Ionic: Fazer o botão confirmar retornar ao primeiro erro do formulário

Tags: ionic, firebase

Olá, estou com um projeto em ionic/firebase e tem nele um formulário com cerca de 31 questoes e preciso que nesta tela ao clicar para concluir ao invés de voltar para o topo como segue nesta função que está no código `this.content.scrollToTop();` eu necessito que ele retorne para a primeira questão inválida. OBS: já tentei muitos tutoriais na internet .
Segue abaixo um trecho do meu .TS:

```
  enviar(abertura: Abertura) {
    if (this.form.form.invalid) {
      let confirmAlert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Parece que há alguma questão sem marcar!',
        message: 'Para proseguir, marque o que está faltando!',
        buttons: [
          {
            text: 'Voltar',
            handler: () => {
              console.log('Voltar clicado');
              this.content.scrollToTop();
            }
          },
        ]
      });
      confirmAlert.present();
    }
```

Comment: Já tentou colocar foco no elemento inválido?

Answer (score 0):

Em vez de usar a função `this.content.scrollToTop()`, você pode usar `this.content.scrollTo(x, y, duracao)`. Para encontrar a posição y do elemento, você pode usar a propriedade `offsetTop`.

Comment: renata no caso eu teria que colocar uma posição x em cada questão?

Comment: Como você identifica a questão que não foi respondida? Nessa função você pode identificar o elemento em que buscará o offsetTop.

Comment: entendi obgd, vou tenatr executar o codigo

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar HTML puro com hyperlink segue exemplo:

Crie o atributo em suas perguntas

```
<h2 id="Pergunta1">Pergunta 1</h2>
```

quando você quiser navegar para a pergunta 1 crie um hyperlink dinamicamente

```
<a href="#Pergunta1">Pule para pergunta 1</a>
```